# AWS Toolkit VS2017 will deploy on fresh instance, won't update

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, visual-studio-2017

I have a VS project I can successfully publish to a fresh instance on elastic beanstalk. When I try to update an instance I created previously using the same wizard the exact same app won't deploy. I get:

```
[Instance: i-0000002f61519a900 ConfigSet: Infra-WriteRuntimeConfig, Infra-WriteApplication1, Infra-WriteApplication2, Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild, Hook-PreAppDeploy, Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild, Hook-EnactAppDeploy, Hook-PostAppDeploy] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: null.
```

If i look in the logs on the actual server itself I find the following problem in C:\cfn\log\cfn-init.log

```
2017-05-09 21:17:27,260 [INFO] Running config Infra-WriteApplication2
2017-05-09 21:17:27,290 [WARNING] Unsupported OS for setting owner/group: nt
2017-05-09 21:17:27,292 [ERROR] Could not move     C:\cfn\download_version_bundle.ps1.bak2 to    cfn\download_version_bundle.ps1.bak
2017-05-09 21:17:27,292 [WARNING] Error restoring backup file C:\cfn\download_version_bundle.ps1.bak: Could not rename C:\cfn\download_version_bundle.ps1.bak2: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
2017-05-09 21:17:32,071 [INFO] Command 01downloadVersion succeeded
2017-05-09 21:17:32,094 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2017-05-09 21:17:32,098 [INFO] Running configSet Hook-PreAppDeploy
2017-05-09 21:17:32,098 [INFO] Running config Hook-PreAppDeploy
2017-05-09 21:17:34,334 [INFO] Command hooks succeeded
2017-05-09 21:17:34,357 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
2017-05-09 21:17:34,361 [INFO] Running configSet Hook-EnactAppDeploy
2017-05-09 21:17:34,361 [INFO] Running config Hook-EnactAppDeploy
2017-05-09 21:17:38,357 [ERROR] Command hooks (HooksExecutor.exe appdeploy\enact) failed
2017-05-09 21:17:38,357 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of Hook-EnactAppDeploy: Command hooks failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 519, in run_config
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 126, in run_commands
  File "cfnbootstrap\command_tool.pyc", line 117, in apply
ToolError: Command hooks failed
2017-05-09 21:17:38,357 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
2017-05-09 21:17:38,357 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command hooks failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cfn-init", line 171, in <module>
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 118, in build
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 505, in build
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 519, in run_config
  File "cfnbootstrap\construction.pyc", line 126, in run_commands
  File "cfnbootstrap\command_tool.pyc", line 117, in apply
ToolError: Command hooks failed
```

running Visual Studio 2017, toolkit version 1.12.0.0